# How to build a script to stop infinite scrolling in any app

Tags: rooting, scripts

How can I build a code/script to stop infinite scrolling (or scrolling at all) in any app I want to, like YouTube Shorts, IG Reels and Tiktok. Script should not break any app from running at all and other functions should work.

Rooting is permissible.
I think there would be a need to change some code near to Android base.

Comment: "Infinite scrolling" is as far as I know not a base feature of Android, so I don't think you will find code for that in Android. Infinite scrolling is basically loading data from a server and adding new UI elements at run-time when the user scrolls down to a point where the end of the current list is near. This can be implemented in any programming language (Java/Kotlin, Xamarin, ReactNative, HTML in WebView) and in different ways. I the end I would expect that you have to implement an app-specific "fix" for every app you want to stop.

Comment: @Robert So in my phone, I can't do anything about infinite scrolling on third party apps? (Which keeps wasting the time)

Comment: You can uninstall such apps and search for alternatives.

Comment: I guess there are apps that can do time management and prevent the app from opening/running, if it might help instead.